# error: Spread elements in map literals must implement 'Map' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting an error on marked line, please can someone tell me how to implement it, and convert my data into a map. I've no idea about this thing and con't find the solution.

The error - `Spread elements in map literals must implement 'Map'.`

I tried using job.data and job.data.data, but still it won't work.

```
DocumentSnapshot job = await _firestore
        .collection('supervisorJobs')
        .doc(widget.supervisorJobId)
        .get();

......Code.......

 setState(() {
      jobDetail = {
        'id': job.id,
        ...job.data(),           //On this line, I'm getting an error.    
        'order': order,
        'providers': providers
      };
      loading = false;
    });
```

Comment: Since [`DocumentSnapshot.data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/1.0.7/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) returns a `Map<String, dynamic>?`, it might return `null`.  Try using a null-aware spread-operator: `...?job.data()`.  If that doesn't work, can you verify what the static and runtime types are of `job.data()`?

Comment: Nah, it;s not working bro. Please suggest some other method.

Comment: Not working how?  What happens?  As I said, if that doesn't work, please state what the reported static and runtime types are of `job.data()`.  I can't help you if you don't provide additional information.